# ¿Cómo puedo indicar cuando mi matriz está llena?

Tags: java, array, condiciones, booleano

Por ejemplo, tengo dos matrices de diferente tamaño, por ejemplo:

```
int[][] m1 = new int[5][6];
int[][] m2 = new int[5][7];
```

Éstas mismas se estarían llenado de acuerdo a una cola que contiene mucho más datos que sumando las dimensiones de ambas matrices.
Cada elemento de esa cola se estaría llenando aleatoriamente entre las dos matrices, pero, ¿Cómo puedo avisar que se llenó una de las matrices primero, para que los elementos de la cola que aún quedan se vayan a la otra matriz? ¿Debería hacer un booleano, un if?

Comment: Que lenguaje usas y pon lo que has intentado

Comment: Podrías usar Integer en lugar de int, así podrías saber cuando está llena (cuando en ninguna posición tengas un `null`)